# Getting a Session-scoped Bean Results in "No Scope registered for scope 'session' "

Tags: spring, session

I'm in an older Spring app which doesn't use annotations.

My task is very simple, get a Session Bean from applicationContext.xml (inside a Struts action), but getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'session'
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">

    <!-- Session-scoped bean -->
    <bean id="techSuppRoleUserInPROD" class="myapp.util.TechSuppRoleUserInPROD" 
     scope="session" />
```

Attempting to get it from this sample Struts Action:

```
public class LandingAction extends ActionSupport {

   public String execute() {

        // 1. Obtain ApplicationContext
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = 
 new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml");

        // 2.Obtain managed session bean
        TechSuppRoleUserInPROD techSuppRoleUserInPROD = (TechSuppRoleUserInPROD)
                     applicationContext.getBean("techSuppRoleUserInPROD");

   }

}
```

Comment: Don't create an application context because you need a bean. If you do this you are doing it in the wrong way. Setup proper spring and struts integration and do dependency injection.

Comment: Yes the problem was I didn't set up a RequestContextListener in web.xml.